# Chance of getting a car toy in a chocolate

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

A mom brings her child every day a chocolate with a toy inside, the toy is random. The boy is happy when he gets a car as a toy. His mom decided to look in which supermarket the probability of getting a car is the highest.

The mom has come to the following result:
Supermarket A:$0.2$ ,Supermarket B:$0.3$, Supermarket C:$0.1$, Supermarket D: $0.05$.

The mom doesn't always buy the chocolate at the same supermarket. 
The frequency of visiting the exact supermarket is:
Supermarket A:$0.2$ ,Supermarket B:$0.4$, Supermarket C:$0.25$, Supermarket D: $0.15$.

1. How high is the probability that the boy gets a car in his chocolate?
2. He found a car in his chocolate. How high is the probability that his mother bought the chocolate at supermarket C?

I am pretty lost here. Do not know even where to start. My assumption is that this has something to do with conditional probability, but I cannot see how to divide this is in events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Law of total probability:
$$
P(car)=P(car|A)P(A)+P(car|B)P(B)+P(car|C)P(C)+P(car|D)P(D)
$$
Then Bayes rule:
$$
P(C|car)=\frac{P(car|C)P(C)}{P(car)}
$$

Comment: Thanks , I was looking at the Bayes rule, but wasn't quite sure how to apply it. The event car is equal to "getting a car in the chocolate" , and P(A),...,P(D) is the probability of the visited store?

Comment: Yes that is so.

Comment: So is the following correct? 

1. $P(car)=0.2\cdot 0.2+0.3\cdot 0.4+0.1\cdot 0.25+0.05\cdot 0.15=0.18575$ 

              
  2. $P(C|car)=\frac{0.1\cdot 0.25}{1}=0.025$

Comment: The denominator is supposed to be P(car)